# Using same flask server for HTTP and Websockets

Tags: http, server, websockets

I have a simple app which has the following architecture:

```
front-end
   api/
back-end
   server.py
   api/
   utils/
```

The app is already using http based server which is started/configured in the server.py. However, now I would also like to use websockets for some new functionalities, while my old http -based code will still be used throughout the app.

My question is, should I create another, separate server for the websockets? Should I decouple the code from the server.py into two files (http server and websocket server)? What are the pros/cons for each approach and is it possible to use the same server for both, the http requests coming in and the websocket connections?

Comment: You should look at [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are looking to separate. Or what is your definition of app.

You can keep everything under `server.py` that is not an issue. However, do provide separate flask objects for HTTP and websockets.

HTTP can probably be handled by a threaded server. Websockets, on the other hand, are much more likely to be a bad idea to use threads. So let the deployment decide what runs what protocol.